# The results of search without gridview doesn't displaying in Yii2

Tags: search, yii2

I tried to organize searching form from 2 fields. But it doesn't display the results. It just staying in site/index . Help me please

**code from siteController.php**

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $driver = new Driver();

    if ($driver->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $driver = Driver::find()
            ->where(['from' => $driver->from])
            ->andWhere(['to' => $driver->to])
            ->all();

        return $this->render('search', ['driver' => $driver]);
    }
    else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Input data not found' );
    }
}
```

**code from models/Driver.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use Yii;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "driver".
 *
 * @property string $id
 * @property string $from
 * @property string $to
 * @property string $data
 * @property string $about
 * @property string $car
 */
class Driver extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'driver';
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
//            [['from', 'to', 'data', 'about', 'car'], 'required'],
            [['about'], 'string'],
            [['from', 'to', 'data', 'car'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'from' => 'From',
            'to' => 'To',
            'data' => 'Data',
            'about' => 'About',
            'car' => 'Car',
        ];
    }

}
```

**code from site/index.php**

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use app\models\Driver;
/* @var $driver app\models\Driver */
?>
<?php
$driver = new Driver;
?>

      <div class="row">

          <div>
              <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
              'action' => ['site/search']
          ]); ?>

              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-5">
                      <?= $form->field($driver, 'from')->label('От')->textInput(['class' => 'input form-control']) ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-5">
                      <?= $form->field($driver, 'to')->label('До')->textInput(['class' => 'input form-control']) ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-2" align="left" style="margin-top: 30px">
                      <input type="image" src="<?= \Yii::getAlias('@web/images/button_search.png')?>" class="icon_button" alt="Поиск" >
                  </div>
              </div>

              <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
          </div>

      </div>
```

**code from site/search.php**

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;

$this->title = "Поиск";

$this->registerMetaTag([
    'name' => 'description',
    'content' => 'driver',
]);
$this->registerMetaTag([
    'name' => 'keywords',
    'content' => 'driver',
])
?>

<?php if (!$driver) { ?>
    <p>Ничего не найдено</p>
<?php } else { ?>


<?php foreach ($driver as $one){
        $from = $one -> from;
        $to = $one -> to;
        $data = $one -> data;
        ?>

            <?php return $this -> render('found_drivers', [
            'from' => $from,
            'to' => $to,
            'data' => $data
        ]); ?>
    <?php  }?>
<?php } ?>
```

**and site/found_drivers.php**

```
<div class="one">
    <h2><?=$id?></h2>
    <hr />
    <table class="">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p><?=$from?></p>
            </td>
            <td class="right">

            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <p><?=$to?></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="">
        <?=$data?> <br>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you let me know if the form is posting at all?  Also on another note you will want to use $this->render('found_driver') in the search.php file instead of include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a form in `site/index` and it's submitting to the same page. If you want to handle the data of your form in another action you need to add it in your form:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['site/search']
]);
```

More info [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$action-detail).

And, as @makie said in the comments, you should use [render()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#render()-detail) instead of [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to render partial views.

Comment: I have update site/index.php _add [ 'action' => ['site/search'] ] in $form = ActiveForm::begin();_  and update site/search add _ <?php return $this -> render('found_drivers'); ?> _inside <?php foreach ($driver as $one){ ?> <?php  }?>_ . But now  Undefined variable: **one**
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic21\views\site\found_drivers.php at line 2
`<div class="one">
    <h2><?=$one-> id?></h2>
    <hr />
    <table class="">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p><?=$one-> from?></p>
            </td>
            <td class="right">
 
            </td>`

Comment: You need to pass the variables as parametes. Like you do in your controller: `render('file-name-without-dot-php', ['variable1' => $variable1, 'variable2' => $variable2])`

Comment: I update `site/search.php` as you said add `<?php return $this -> render('found_drivers', ['from' => $from, 'to' => $to]); ?>` . But it says that `Undefined variable: from` and `Undefined variable: to` . You now i am a newbie in Yii2 and somethimes i can't catch fully.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You never declared a `$from` variable. `<?php foreach ($driver as $one) { return $this->render('found_drivers', ['one' => $one]); }; ?>`

Comment: do you mean like this? `  <?php foreach ($driver as $one){
  $from = $one -> from;
  $to = $one -> to;
  $data = $one -> data;
  ?>

   <?php return $this -> render('found_drivers', [
   'from' => $from,
   'to' => $to,
   'data' => $data
  ]); ?>
  <?php  }?>`. Now error is **Trying to get property of non-object**  `<?php foreach ($driver as $one){
        $from = $**one** -> from;
        $to = $one -> to;
        $data = $one -> data;
        ?>` i thought that **one** is equal to the new _driver_ in the cycle. $driver is an object but it seems **one** is not

Comment: In your controller, you made a search for one `Driver` and send the result as `$driver` (object) to the view. There is no reason for a `foreach`. You need to remove this `foreach` or change that search to `all()` intead of `one()`.

Comment: @ Clyff thank's a lot  it's working :) finally but after that i transfered all cod from the site/found_drivers to the site/search